# How to Determine Minimum and Maximum Degree Of Chart Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I have an wheel of fortune from chart and javascript code. I copy [https://www.codewithrandom.com/2023/11/24/spin-wheel-app-using-javascript/](this site) and everything is working fine.

What I want to do is reduce or increase the prize, in that example the prize are 12 items, here is the code

```
/* --------------- Minimum And Maximum Angle For A value  --------------------- */
const spinValues = [
  { minDegree: 61, maxDegree: 90, value: 100 },
  { minDegree: 31, maxDegree: 60, value: 200 },
  { minDegree: 0, maxDegree: 30, value: 300 },
  { minDegree: 331, maxDegree: 360, value: 400 },
  { minDegree: 301, maxDegree: 330, value: 500 },
  { minDegree: 271, maxDegree: 300, value: 600 },
  { minDegree: 241, maxDegree: 270, value: 700 },
  { minDegree: 211, maxDegree: 240, value: 800 },
  { minDegree: 181, maxDegree: 210, value: 900 },
  { minDegree: 151, maxDegree: 180, value: 1000 },
  { minDegree: 121, maxDegree: 150, value: 1100 },
  { minDegree: 91, maxDegree: 120, value: 1200 },
];
/* --------------- Size Of Each Piece  --------------------- */
const size = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
/* --------------- Background Colors  --------------------- */
var spinColors = [
  "#E74C3C",
  "#7D3C98",
  "#2E86C1",
  "#138D75",
  "#F1C40F",
  "#D35400",
  "#138D75",
  "#F1C40F",
  "#b163da",
  "#E74C3C",
  "#7D3C98",
  "#138D75",
];

labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I try to reduce the items become 10 items, with this code (I modified my self) and also find my own formula with minDegree and MaxDegree for spinValues

```
/* --------------- Minimum And Maximum Angle For A value  --------------------- */
const spinValues = [
  { minDegree: 73, maxDegree: 108, value: 100 },
  { minDegree: 37, maxDegree: 72, value: 200 },
  { minDegree: 0, maxDegree: 36, value: 300 },
  { minDegree: 325, maxDegree: 360, value: 400 },
  { minDegree: 289, maxDegree: 324, value: 500 },
  { minDegree: 253, maxDegree: 288, value: 600 },
  { minDegree: 217, maxDegree: 252, value: 700 },
  { minDegree: 181, maxDegree: 216, value: 800 },
  { minDegree: 145, maxDegree: 180, value: 900 },
  { minDegree: 109, maxDegree: 144, value: 1000 },
];
/* --------------- Size Of Each Piece  --------------------- */
const size = [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12];
/* --------------- Background Colors  --------------------- */
var spinColors = [
  "#E74C3C",
  "#7D3C98",
  "#2E86C1",
  "#138D75",
  "#F1C40F",
  "#D35400",
  "#138D75",
  "#F1C40F",
  "#b163da",
  "#E74C3C",
];

labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

But it goes wrong somehow, See the picture I attach
[The arrow show to labels 6 but the prize value is 700](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLpLz.png)
[The arrow show to labels 2 but the prize value is 300](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soDt7.png)

Its work when its in default 12 items, when arrow show to label 6, the prize value would be 600.

I think there's some mistake in determine **Minimum And Maximum Angle For A value** in script.
The formula I use to get 10 Items
`360/10`
[formula in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVPgr.png)

What I ask, how to determine the minimum and maximum angle (degree) for the items show?
I want to use **foreach function in PHP** to show the item with minimum and maximum angle (minDegree and MaxDegree for spinValues) so that I can increase or reduce the total of items easily.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you right about the formula
360/10

What you need is to sort the spinValues in ascending array. Then edit your size like this code

```
const size = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
```

No need to make the size larger than "1" because if all number is same, it will be split into same piece.
Now make sure to change your arrow of wheel to the top and not at right

```
.container img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 4em;
    top: -5%;
    right: 44%;
    transform:rotate(-93deg);
}
```

Now you will have right value what arrow show. Hope this helps you

Comment: yes this was usefull things, But I have to re-value my array. Thanks before